# Archiving repeated tasks

Tags: org-mode

When I archive a repeated task (let's say, a learning project of 15 minutes every Wednesday day for 2 month), the task gets archived in a date tree all under the day it was closed (cancelled) as a whole (to avoid repetition), with having under LOG all individual instances of repetition. It would be great if each of these individual "task happenings" were archived under the date and time they were completed individually, and not just all as one block. Not sure if I made myself understood! :))

Comment: I understand. I have similar issues with archiving, as it seems to conflict with the goal of maintaining a clear log of work done. Currently, I keep recurring tasks in one file, and link to the task in my daily log. That way the daily log has a permanent record of the activity, and it won't be obscured when I archive the task.

Comment: Thanks! How can I do that automatically? Care to share your implementation? ;)

Comment: It's a work in progress. At this point, I'm doing it mostly by hand: `org-store-link` to grab the link to the current heading, then move to today's journal file and `org-insert-link` to add the link to a list of activities for the day. When I get some time, I'll write a function to `store-link-to-this-todo-in-todays-journal` or something like that. Haven't decided if I need to support interactively picking a day, or if I will only ever need to send the link to today's journal.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Tyler, that's a lot of work! I have many repeated tasks every day, I can't afford doing that. I archive maybe once a month, so imagine :) I can't just spend a day doing that. I would like that when I hit on a specific shortcut for archiving each logged entry goes to the right date tree place.

Comment: After looking into the capture documentation, it's actually pretty easy to automate this. You can use the `%a` symbol in a capture template to automatically insert a link to the location you were in when you called capture. That reduces my workflow above to: with point in the item you want to link, call capture, complete capture. That's it. I imagine you could customize/streamline that to make it pretty quick and easy.

Comment: That may work for capturing, but what about all the TODOs already set up for repeated tasks?